# Nodejs & Express: How to send multiple Json variable from server to Client through response.send()

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, itunes-search-api

I am developing an nodejs search application for [itunes-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/itunes-search) and searching some software information from my local database with [express framework](http://expressjs.com/). The search module returns information like software name, music name through a single json variable. But now I also need Music artist details/ Software company name through another different json variable. I can simply return the song details with the bellowed code. 
In client sides:

```
$scope.search_music_data = function(data)
{
  var data="Hamdoon Soft";//Search my favourite artist name or band name
    $http({'method' : 'post', url: '/search', data: {'search_item' : data}}).
    success(function(data){ 
        $scope.artist_name = data; 
    }).
    error(function(data){ 
    })
    $scope.check = true;
}
```

Bellowed codes are in server sides:

In route.js

```
app.post('/search', search.search_music);
```

In search_music function currently this code is working:

```
ItemName="calculated data Json Data"
var response.send(ItemName);
```

But I also need send another calculated data like

```
  ItemName="calculated data Json Data"
  ArtistName="calculated data Json Data"
  var response.send(ItemName, ArtistName);
```

Or    ItemName="calculated data Json Data"
      SoftWareCompnayName="calculated data Json Data"
      var response.send(ItemName, SoftWareCompnayName);
Is it possible?I will really appreciate him/her if he/she can help me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use this in server side code. I think this will help you. This is the example of multiple value sent from server to client.

```
res.send({artist: artist_details, music: music_details});
```

In client side :

you can access it data.artist & data.music from angular controller.

Comment: You may need to JSON.parse(data) in the client when it comes back before you can access artist and music from the object.

Answer (score 1):

so you could pass an object to response.send method which that object will include your song and artist info.

```
var data = {
  song: ..,
  artist: ..
};

response.send(data);
```

---

I tried itunes-search but it throws an error when I got started using it, so I created my [own module](https://gist.github.com/wilsonbalderrama/3a2b7225e4a805314c91#file-itunes-js) that do the same task as itunes-search.

This is my example using my own method **getSongsAndArtistInfo** which returns an object containing songs and artist info properties:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var itunes = require('./itunes');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/search', function (req, res) {
  var searchItem = req.body.searchItem;
  itunes.getSongsAndArtistInfo(searchItem, function (err, result) {
    if (err) res.status(404).send(err);

    res.send(result);
  });
});

app.listen(4000, function () {
  console.log('server up and running at 4000 port');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have more than one res.write() but only one res.send()...

```
res.write("object")
res.write("object")
res.send()
```